# Bijection btw oncordance classes and homtopic maps to representing space of a sheaf

Tags: ct.category-theory, moduli-spaces, riemann-surfaces

In Madsen and Weiss's [paper](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v165-n3-p04.pdf) Appendix A.1 (pp.925) there is an important theorem asserting a bijection between concondance classes and homotopy classes of maps to the representing space of a sheaf of set

$$ \mathcal{F}[X] \xrightarrow{\hspace{0.3cm}\cong\hspace{0.3cm}} [X,|\mathcal{F}|] $$ where $[X,|\mathcal{F}|]$ is the set of homotopy classes of continuous maps $X \to |\mathcal{F}|$

The key step of the construction for both the forward and inverse map is the definition of a smooth homotopy $h_t: X \to X$ that defines a so-called extended triangulation for $X$.  In Dan Freed's [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture21.pdf) Theorem 21.38 he refers that as the construction of a vector field on $X$ from its smooth triangulation which pushes towards lower dimensional simplices.  I can't see how Madsen and Weiss's construction can be interpreted from the vector field perspective let alone the mysterious phrase of "pushes towards lower dimensional simplices".  Could somebody help to clarify?